# Toilet weak flush. The water in the bowl swirls, but it didn't flush stuff into the pipe

Tags: toilet

Updated on 07/Dec

More pictures and I kind of knowing why. The last picture is when it's flushing. I found the water only comes out from the top of the rim, and there's no water comes out from the bottom of the rim. This makes the direction of the flushing water can't really PUSH the stuff into the pipe. I also have a look at other toilets, they behave the same. Maybe I worry in the wrong direction.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Updated on 06/Dec

I tried to unclog it by toilet auger. It worked a bit since I pulled out something dirty stuck in the pipe. I did it three times and also lubricate it with dishwasher and hot water. However, the flush is still weak. What I can reckon is, the water in the bowel will be replaced by the flush water. It's the stuff in the bowel didn't get flush down into the pipe. Might be an issue with the toilet itself? Maybe all I need to do is to change a new toilet?

EDIT:

Attached more pictures of my toilet bowl.

[image]
[image]

[Here is the video.](https://youtu.be/_yis7i0M_Aw)

I put some toilet papers in the bowl and flush it. From the video, it shows the toilet papers just kept swirling in the bowl and there's no absorption happened to pull things into the pipe.

First, I'm sure the water level in the tanks has been set to maximum.

I also have tested this toilet by quickly pouring a big bucket of water to see whether the flush happens. Unfortunately, no matter how much water I pour, no flush happens. What I saw is a lot of water in the bowl and the water level quickly comes back to its origin. No absorption happened. Unlike the bucket test video I saw.

I  then doubted might be a blocker in the pipe causing the flush is weak. I pour drain unblocker liquid into the bowl and flush it after waiting for a while. However, the flush is still very weak.

Actually, the plumbers came to here two weeks before and told me it's the tank cause the problem. They replaced the tank, but the problem still exists and they just disappeared and not answer my call. (It's another sad story)

£400 for the plumber and they didn't fix it. I don't want to be scammed again. I googled and studied in order to let myself understand the situation a bit more. But after trying all the possible solutions, nothing really works.

I came here for seeking advice and help. Any thought is very much welcome and appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to DIY StackExchange! For everyone's info, the video is safe to watch. Just water flushing (phew!). So when you dump a bucket of water into the toilet, it doesn't flush either? How big is the bucket? Have you tried to plunge the toilet? Has it always been weak or did it happen all a sudden ?

Comment: Hi @HazardousGlitch, it didn't flush when I dumped about 3 gallons of water. I also have plunged the toilet, but no improvement. It has been this weak since I moved to here for about a month.

Comment: I'm sure you know this now, but next time do not pay the plumber until you see it working to your satisfaction.  It may make for an uncomfortable confrontation, but sadly this is sometimes necessary.  Also, have you tried calling the plumber back, if he's reputable he should return and take another look.

Comment: Did you dump the 3 gallons in quickly, like within 3 seconds and after dumping in the water, how long did it take for the water to fall down?

Comment: @GaryBak Thank you. You're right with the necessary confrontation and I really learned the lesson. I called him several times, but he just ignored my call and didn't reply to any text message either. Sad.

Comment: @GaryBak Thanks again. Yes, I definitely dump it within 3 secs. It took about 2-3 secs for the water to fall down.

Comment: Just to be clear: this is a washdown toilet (no "glug-glug-glug" at the end, only uses rushing water to remove waste, doesn't produce a siphon effect, often found in Europe), not a siphon toilet (goes "glug-glug-glug" at the end due to a siphon  effect, often found in USA), right?

Comment: The in-flow looks kind of slow to me, (but different countries have different toilet designs) I'd check that the valve on the tank is opening correctly.

Comment: @DanielGriscom, I think you're right. It's a washdown toilet. Is there a way to know it? I can't find any model name on the toilet.

Comment: @Jasen The plumber replace it with a new tank. I also just checked the valve. When I push down, I can tell the flapper lift up and the valve is open. But I do also think the in-flow is slow.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things that could be causing your problem. A partially plugged drain slowing the water. Or a plugged vent that is not allowing the water because a vacuum is being created.

For me, when I have a slow drain like this I will use a toilet auger to make sure the toilet it self is clear (had a kid flush a dead light bulb and did not find it until using the auger, which broke the bulb).

If the auger makes no difference, I pull the toilet. It's not that hard, just a bit messy. Turn the water off, disconnect & flush the toilet. A shop vac is handy here to remove reaming water. Remove 2 bolts anchoring the toilet to the floor. Lift the toilet, and now you can see the drain and possibly the wax seal on the flange (or on the toilet).  I use rubber gloves and a small putty knife to scrape off the old seal. Was it centered?  It could be the problem if not centered.

At this point I run a snake down the line, and I also examine what I can see. Has somebody poured grease down the toilet? Found that quite a few times, but usually the snake fixes the problem. In rare cases, I have found a dead squirrel in the vent line and a bird's nest but a plugged vent can cause problems also, but usually other drains in the bath also have problems if this is the case.

Once the line is snaked clean, I press a new seal on the toilet (I like the ones with the urethane core but a solid wax ring is cheaper, just a few bucks). Place the toilet back on the flange and put the 2 anchor bolts in. Connect the water and give it a try.

Chemical drain cleaners usually don't work well on toilets because of the large volume of water and if the water is slowly draining it won't be in contact long enough to do any good. After my troubles with a flushed light bulb I now auger the toilet because that one cost me hours to figure out. The bulb was stuck in the toilet trap. And water would run slowly but not flush.

Comment: I've seen toys and other, um, items stuck in the toilet but never a light bulb! Interesting.

Comment: I would say fill a sink basin or tub, do those drain fast or slow? I would just check that before lifting the toilet just in case they have it also, it will save time and frustrations having to reinstall the toilet. If there is no difference, then you wouls still have to remove toilet to do the remaining steps.

Comment: Hi, @noybman. Thank you. Both the sink basin and tub drain very fast.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ed Beal. I will definitely try the toilet snake first. I'm pretty sure the plumbers didn't apply toilet snake when they were here.

Comment: I tried to unclog it by toilet auger. It worked a bit since I saw there's something dirty stuck in the pipe. I did it three times and also lubricate it with dishwasher and hot water. However, the flush is still weak. What I can reckon is, the water in the bowel will be replaced by the flush water. It's the stuff in the bowel didn't get flush down into the pipe. I tried to do whatever I can, I might need to change the whole toilet which has a better flush system?

Comment: Now that you have added photos that is a different style toilet than I have worked on is the tank in the ceiling? The physics should still be similar once water fills the bowl gravity should still drain the water if not constricted.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you. I have attached more pictures to bring a better understanding of the toilet layout. It's not in the ceiling, it's actually behind the toilet. There's a chance that the height is not enough to bring the gravity power. If I use a bucket of water, things can be flushed into the pipe.